# Observed info matrix via Hessian

Tags: expected-value, matrix, fisher-information

In some resources, I saw that the observed information matrix is the negative of the expected value of the Hessian matrix. However, in some other resources I saw that it is just the negative of the Hessian. Also, in R this is calculated by the inverse of the Hessian matrix (no negative). I am extremely confused. Can you please explain this?

Comment: Can you pinpoint some of the resources?